# Can I use an attr_writer with a Postgres Array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have a collection of checkboxes that save an array of responses to the database, in a Postgres array column. The problem is that unchecked options come through as empty strings, so I end up with

```
['a', '', 'c']
```

If I try to setup an attr_writer to clean the array on save:

```
def multiple_response=(val)
  val.compact_blank
end
```

or even just

```
attr_writer :multiple_response
```

Then nothing is saved to the database. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: 1) Not sure why `['a', '', 'c']` is a problem. It indicates that 3 choices where available and only 2 where checked. 2) What do you want to happen with the unchecked options? **Add answer as update to question**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you need, after removing blanks, you should call super, ActiveRecord's method for saving the attribute:

```rb
def multiple_response=(val)
  super(val.compact_blank)
end
```

Comment: That was it! Thank you! Now I need to learn more about the why...

Comment: Found more information here https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#class-ActiveRecord::Base-label-Overwriting+default+accessors